# HTML5 Canvas Image Clipping

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

Something like I am have in canvas tileset image.
http://i947.photobucket.com/albums/ad320/kev1030_photos/btiles2032.png

How to do something like if I click on first tile return 0, if on 10 tile return 9 and ... and...

How to clip tileset on HTML5 canvas?

Comment: what has clipping got to do with it?  It appears you want to know how to calculate a "box number" given a coordinate on the canvas?

Comment: I am need to do something like this - http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ayDycuPPd60

Comment: that's not how this place works - reduce your problem to _defined_, _bite size_ chunks, and you might get some help.  Also let people know what you already tried.

Comment: guys give him a bit of a break, I don't think he's a native English speaker, and it can be very hard to define a problem well if you don't have the vocabulary for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clip is not the right word here. Clipping is when you only draw part of an image or path to the screen.

You would call this "hit testing" or "object picking" or "cell detection".

This is just simple math. Each icon is 32 + 2 yellow, so you can do this to find out which cell:

```
can.addEventListener('mousedown', function(e) {
    var mouse = getMouse(e, can);
    var x = Math.floor(mouse.x / 34);
    var y = Math.floor(mouse.y / 34);
    alert(x + (y*16)); // because there are 16 in a row
}, false);
```

Here's a working example:

http://jsfiddle.net/YH8b8/